# $T$ continous at $0 \Rightarrow \lVert Tx\rVert \leq M \lVert x \rVert $

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question regarding the following proof
Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces and $T: X \rightarrow Y$ a linear map.
\begin{equation}
T \text{ is continuous at } 0 \Rightarrow \exists M \geq 0 \text{ such that } \lVert Tx\rVert \leq M \lVert x \rVert
\end{equation}

Let's assume the condition on the right side to be false.
Then there exists for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ an $x_n \in X$ such that
$\lVert Tx_n\rVert >n \lVert x_n \rVert$. Defining
$y_n=\frac{x_n}{n \lVert x_n \rVert}$, we have $\lVert y_n \rVert =\frac{1}{n}$, but $\lVert Ty_n\rVert=\frac{\lVert Tx_n \rVert}{n \lVert x_n \rVert}>1$, which is a contradiction to the assumption that $T$ is continuous in $0$.

Question: What is the reason we can define $y_n$, as is. Or in other words, why is denominator $\neq 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\| Tx_n \| > n \| x_n \|$, it follows that $\| T x_n \| > 0$.  Therefore $Tx_n \neq 0$.  Since $T$ is linear, $T$ takes $0$ to $0$, and thus $Tx_n \neq 0$ implies $x_n \neq 0$.  Hence $\| x_ n \| \neq 0$.